# With a T-SQL function, how can I return an integer from a count(*) function?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

I am simply trying to return the `count(*)` integer value that is produced from the select. This is my first attempt at functions.

I have tried my inner statements out of the function and all works as I expect.  This returns the table, but what I really want is just to return an integer of what the `count(*)` returns. How can I do this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LogicMatchCount
    (@logic varchar(1000),
      @tags varchar(1000) )
 RETURNS TABLE
 AS 
    RETURN  
        WITH  LogicTagTable AS 
        (
             SELECT TRIM(VALUE) AS logic_tag
             FROM string_split(@logic, '&')
         ),
         DonorTagTable AS 
        (
           SELECT TRIM(VALUE) donor_tag
           FROM string_split(@tags, ',')
         )              
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS TagMatchCount
         FROM LogicTagTable ltt
         INNER JOIN DonorTagTable dtt ON dtt.donor_tag = ltt.logic_tag;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you returning a **table** - if you really only want to return a **single atomic value** ??

Comment: I don't know how to do it.  I tried RETURNS INT but then it gives an error when returning -- something to do with the WITH statement???

Comment: Ha, it was because the statement preceding the common table expression wasn't terminated with a semicolon.   If you don't want declare a variable, per marc_s's answer below, just add set nocount on; as the first line of the scalar function

Answer (score 1):

Since you really only want to return a **single atomic value** - use a scalar-valued function instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LogicMatchCount
    (@logic varchar(1000),
     @tags varchar(1000))
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CountResult INT;
    
    WITH LogicTagTable AS 
    (
        SELECT TRIM(VALUE) AS logic_tag
        FROM string_split(@logic, '&')
    ),
    DonorTagTable AS 
    (
        SELECT TRIM(VALUE) donor_tag
        FROM string_split(@tags, ',')
    )
    SELECT @CountResult = COUNT(*) 
    FROM LogicTagTable ltt
    INNER JOIN DonorTagTable dtt ON dtt.donor_tag = ltt.logic_tag;
    
    RETURN @CountResult;
END;
```

and then call it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.LogicMatchCount('....', '....');
```

Comment: @Sm00thSailn, remember to mark Marc_S' answer as the correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps slightly different approach

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.svfLogicMatchCount
    (@logic varchar(1000),
     @tags varchar(1000)   )
Returns int as  
Begin 
   Return ( 
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM ( SELECT TRIM(VALUE) AS logic_tag
                     FROM string_split(@logic, '&')
                 ) ltt
            INNER JOIN (
                          SELECT TRIM(VALUE) donor_tag
                          FROM string_split(@tags, ',')
                       ) dtt ON dtt.donor_tag = ltt.logic_tag
          )
End
```

Comment: Very concise.  Thanks.

Comment: Strange that begin .. end is needed when returning a scalar value but not a table